# General solution to a recursive rational equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have this problem which states that:

$$a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}}{4}\left(1-\frac{63}{a_{n-1}^3+7}\right),\text{ and }a_1=c$$

I have tried numerous ways to solve it by hand, as well as Wolfram Mathematica's RSolve function, with no success. The following is the command in Wolfram Mathematica:

```
RSolve[{a[n] == a[n-1]/4*(1-63/((a[n-1])^3+7)), a[1] == 1}, a[n], n]
```

I cannot get the closed form for $a_n$. Could anybody help please?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Why would you expect a nice formula to exist?

Comment: I would be very surprised by a closed form. Did you try to comute the first terms ?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that this non-linear difference equation has a simple closed solution.

As long as $a_n$ is small(ish), it will grow exponentially as $(9/4)^n$, once it gets large, it will decay as $4^{-n}$, until it gets small, and...

Play around with some values of $a_0 = c$ of interest, see if something interesting develops. Refine your question with specific $c$.